# excel data same row

Tags: excel

I'm trying to write an Excel Function that grabs the data out of a neighboring cell ***in the same row***. What is the proper function to do this? I've been searching for hours and cannot find it.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Maybe you can post a bit of your code so we can get a better idea of what you're doing?

Comment: I haven't written any yet, I just want the cell to grab data relative to where it is located. (in the same row) For example, I want every cell in the 'E' column to have the value of it's coresponding 'C' column. So it would grab the data from the "same-row" 'C' column cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps Offset would suit: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/offset.php

Comment: This looks like it would work but how do I set the 'reference' cell to the one containing the function?

Comment: Not VBA, just in Excel (it's a cell function) - take a look at the offset parameters; range, etc etc etc. The range is like the "base" cell, but I need it to be relative to the cell in which the function is inserted. Do you know how to reference it "self". (like in jquery/js, you would just put 'this' as the range)

Comment: i don't believe that in-cell excel functions work like that. it's more absolute, where the cell references an exact other cell to grab data. however, excel does a lot of the legwork for you should rows/columns modify so that you aren't always updating your references.

Answer (score 3):

The question is answered in this thread:
[Self-reference for cell, column and row in worksheet functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335563/self-reference-for-cell-column-and-row-in-worksheet-functions)

To get the data of a cell in the same row left to your cell you can use:

=INDIREKT(ADRESSE(ZEILE(); SPALTE()-1))

(German Excel)

=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()-1))

(English Excel, not tested)

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to grab info in column A and maybe multiply it by something in column B in your B cell you would do:

```
=A1*2
```

Is this what you're talking about? This seems maybe too straightforward...

**EDIT** Try this:

```
=$A1*2
```

and then drag the little square in the lower right corner of the cell down as many rows as you need.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, only relative, so it will work in any row, not just A1's row.

Comment: are you just writing an in cell function or a VBA macro?

Comment: Cell function - take a look at the offset comment, it will work but I need to know how you reference "it's own cell" for the range.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was written over 2 years ago but I was as frustrated as you were when I couldn't so I thought I'd post it here. All you do is put a dollar sign ($) in front of the row or column that you want to reference. So, for example if you wanted to get data from column C but using varying rows, you would write it like this:

```
$C1
```

It's called a mixed cell reference. Source: [Introducing Excel Formulas](http://www.cob.sjsu.edu/splane_m/excelformulas.htm)