# Modify values without creating a new column

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to replace the value of a cell with the result of a formula which refers to the cell itself. I tried to allow circular reference (1 cycle) but it didn't help.

Say I have a number in cell `A1` (and cells below), I would like to replace its content with the following formula: `=A1/60` (the same for the rest of the column).

Of course I can do that with a new column on the side, but I would like to achieve this without inserting a new column. Or maybe create some automation that adds a new one far away, do stuff and then removes it.

Comment: use a Macro which taking cells as parameter !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a UDF in Excel to update the worksheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433096/using-a-udf-in-excel-to-update-the-worksheet)

Comment: Have a look at [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335563/self-reference-for-cell-column-and-row-in-worksheet-functions) SO question, it may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the cells you want to change and run this small macro:

```
Sub FormulaMaker()
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        V = r.Value
        If V = "" Then V = 0
        r.Formula = "=" & V & "/60"
    Next r
End Sub
```

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 3):

- Enter `60` in a cell somewhere and copy it.
- Select `ColumnA`  ..... *FILE* .... *Clipboard* ..... *Paste* - *Paste Special*
- Then check  *Divide*, press *OK*

Comment: who knows, it's likely to be a peril of editing/commenting elsewhere. Its the best answer here.