# How to add value in relative cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to know if there is another way of adding `B1`, `C1` and `D1` per my example below other than using a regular sum.

I want to make something like:

> E1 = COLUMN(column of E1 - 1)ROW(1) + COLUMN(column of E1 - 2)ROW(1) + COLUMN(column of E1 - 3)ROW(1)

So that E1 = 4 + 3 + 2

Sorry for troubling you guys. Thanks and regards

[image: excel]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `OFFSET` formula to do this:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(E1,0,-3):OFFSET(E1,0,-1))
```

To make it generic you can follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335563/self-reference-for-cell-column-and-row-in-worksheet-functions) and use this formula:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,-3):OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,-1))
```

Where the formula to get the reference to the current cell is:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())
```

Which then gets substituted into the original formula for each original reference to `E1`.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know if there is function to get E1 address without typing E1?

Answer (score 0):

Putting in `="E1"&"="&B1&"+"&C1&"+"&D1` had the cell come out to `E1=2+3+4`. You'd just have to change `E1` manually if you moved it around.

Answer (score 0):

put the formula in E1 :
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-3))+INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-2))+INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1))